# mvc-mini-profiler not working with jquery.validate.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I've got mvc-mini-profiler installed as suggested in the docs.

I see the tab at the top for simple pages, but it doesnt show on pages with jquery.validate.js  (jQuery validation plug-in 1.7)

Firefox gives:

```
invalid label
{"Id":"a3debe14-f316-4b56-9c61-64954b7...ivialDurationThresholdMilliseconds":2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must have been an incompatibility with jquery.validate 1.7.  Works with jquery.validate 1.8

Comment: I'm still getting it with Validate 1.8.1 and mvc-mini-profiler 1.4, did you change anything else? I'm running jQuery 1.6.2. It also doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: Fixed it, I had a rogue reference to an older jQuery version (1.5.1). It's working fine now.